# create own block styles with template_dir

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

asciidoctor allows you to provide [custom templates](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#provide-custom-templates) through the template_dir option. The documentation seems not to be enough for me to get it going and google is also not of help.

Does anybody know of a good example where a custom template is used?

Basically, I would like to render a block like this

```
[custom]
=====
my custom block
=====
```

with my own style. I copied one of the [default styles](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-backends/tree/master/erb/html5), renamed it and specified a template_dir, but all I currently get is an error message saying `invalid style for example block: custom`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that for using custom templates, you have to register some special class/code in asciidoc. But I found another solution

```
[role="custom"]
====
my custom block
====
```

will assign the class "custom" to the rendered div. That's what I basically needed.